# Android: How to keep track of multiple buttons that were clicked when transfer data to another fragment

Tags: android

Hi there I am new to android programming,
I have this xml file and its associated java fragment class

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sisButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/smallButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/sis" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/soeButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/sisButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/soe" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/solButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/sisButton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/sol" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sobButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewNumLockersAvailable"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sisButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="@string/sob" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/allSchoolsButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sobButton"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/sobButton"
    android:text="@string/all" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/smallButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sobButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"

    android:text="@string/small" />



<Button

         android:text="@string/large" />

<Button

       android:text="@string/all" />

  <Button

    android:text="@string/lv1" />

<Button

    android:text="@string/lv2" />

 <Button

         android:text="@string/lv3" />

<Button

    android:text="@string/all" />

  <Button

     android:text="@string/ViewNumLockersAvailable" />

<Button

       android:text="@string/search" />
<Button

    android:text="@string/logout" />



   </RelativeLayout>
```

Question, how do I keep the track of the buttons that were click, when I transfer the data to another fragment

Please help

Answer (score 1):

> *how do I keep the track of the buttons that were click, when I transfer the data to another fragment*

As understood, you're looking for inter-fragment data transfer.  Let your parent-activity handle this transfer (or any other action you'd like) through an interface:

```
public interface InterFragmentDataTransferer {
     public void btnListener(String dataStr1, String dataStr2);
     // You may define here as many other methods as you need.
}
```

Then, implement this interface in your parent-activity, override the method(s) with desired actions & finally instantiate your fragment:

```
public MyFragmentHolderActivity extends Activity implements InterFragmentDataTransferer {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_parent_activity_layout);
        // Do other instantiation jobs;
        // .
        // .
        mFragment = MyFragment.newInstance();

    }

    public void btnListener(String dataStr1, String dataStr2) {
        // You've the desired data here :D ... so do whatever you'd like.
    }
}
```

Finally, you'll get the interface instance inside the caller-fragment inside onAttach method of the fragment, which can be used to pass the data:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

     private InterFragmentDataTransferer mFragDataTransferer;

     public static Fragment newInstance() {
        return new MyFragment();
     }

     @Override
     public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mFragDataTransferer = (InterFragmentDataTransferer) activity;
     }

     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          Log.d(TAG, "inside OncreateView()");
          ViewGroup rv = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                              R.layout.your_layout, container, false);

          (rv.findViewById(R.id.sisButton))
                             .setOnClickListener(this);
          (rv.findViewById(R.id.soeButton))
                             .setOnClickListener(this);
          (rv.findViewById(R.id.solButton))
                             .setOnClickListener(this);
          (rv.findViewById(R.id.sobButton))
                             .setOnClickListener(this);
          (rv.findViewById(R.id.allSchoolsButton))
                             .setOnClickListener(this);
          (rv.findViewById(R.id.smallButton))
                             .setOnClickListener(this);

          // TODO write your other code
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

          switch (v.getId()) {
             case R.id.sisButton:
                 // TODO write button click-action here
                 mFragDataTransferer.btnListener(dataStr1, dataStr2);
                 break;
             case R.id.soeButton:
                 // TODO write button click-action here
                 mFragDataTransferer.btnListener(dataStr1, dataStr2);
                 break;
             case R.id.solButton:
                 // TODO write button click-action here
                 mFragDataTransferer.btnListener(dataStr1, dataStr2);
                 break;
             case R.id.sobButton:
                 // TODO write button click-action here
                 mFragDataTransferer.btnListener(dataStr1, dataStr2);
                 break;
             case R.id.allSchoolsButton:
                 // TODO write button click-action here
                 mFragDataTransferer.btnListener(dataStr1, dataStr2);
                 break;
             case R.id.smallButton:
                 // TODO write button click-action here
                 mFragDataTransferer.btnListener(dataStr1, dataStr2);
                 break;
             default:
                break;
          }
    }
}
```

**Extra tips:** Do not override the fragment constructor to pass the any data/interface, which may throw FragmentInstantiateException, though passing the interface through newInstance() method as param is safer, but also not recommended as I've read.